# unable to install phone gap on El Capitan

Tags: npm, osx-elcapitan, phonegap-cli

I am trying to CLI to install phone gap, though no matter what I try keep getting the following message

```
Pauls-Air% sudo npm install -g phonegap@latest
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
/usr/local/lib
└── (empty)

npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.1.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "phonegap@latest"
npm ERR! node v6.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/async-57de1878
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/async-57de1878' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/localtunnel/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/async'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/async-57de1878' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/localtunnel/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/async'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/paulmcguane/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1


Pauls-Air% npm version
{ npm: '3.8.6',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  http_parser: '2.7.0',
  icu: '56.1',
  modules: '48',
  node: '6.1.0',
  openssl: '1.0.2h',
  uv: '1.9.0',
  v8: '5.0.71.35',
  zlib: '1.2.8' }
```